# Can "who" be omitted in "Managers (who) formerly supervised"?

Tags: word-choice, ellipsis, exam-questions

> Managers formerly **(      )** the software engineering groups for the development project will now be in charge of much larger teams.
>
> A. supervised
>   B. supervising

The answer is B, and I get it, but to me A(supervised) seems correct as well.

> Managers (who) formerly **supervised** the software engineering groups for the development project / will now be in charge of much larger teams.

Why isn't this sentence accepted? is it because I can't omit "who" like I did in the sentence? Or does the verb has to be "(managers who) had supervised ~~"?

Can anyone explain to me why A is not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit *who* and use *supervised*, but ***not*** without adding a pronoun and punctuation. (And possibly a conjunction.)

The reason for this is that the following is an independent clause:

> ✔ Managers formerly ***supervised*** the software engineering groups for the development project.

But this is *not* an independent clause:

> ✘ Will now be in charge of much larger teams.

In order for the above to make sense on its own, it needs a pronoun in front of it.

> ✔ ***They*** will now be in charge of much larger teams.

---

Ways to join the two together include the following:

> ✔ Managers formerly ***supervised*** the software engineering groups for the development project**, and *they*** will now be in charge of much larger teams.
>
> ✔ Managers formerly ***supervised*** the software engineering groups for the development project**; *they*** will now be in charge of much larger teams.
>
> ✔ Managers formerly ***supervised*** the software engineering groups for the development project**. *They*** will now be in charge of much larger teams.

---

But since rephrasing the latter part of the sentence is not given as a possibility, you cannot omit *who* and use *supervised*:

> ✘ Managers formerly ***supervised*** the software engineering groups for the development project <sup><s>*[, and they]*</s></sup> will now be in charge of much larger teams.

---

With the use of *supervising*, neither part of the sentence is an independent clause—nor can it stand on its own. But when joined *together*, the entire sentence becomes a grammatical independent clause:

> ✔ **Managers formerly** ***supervising*** the software engineering groups for the development project ***will*** now be in charge of much larger teams.

Comment: thanks so much, but why can't I see ("Managers formerly supervised ~") as a whole a subject? Like "Subject" will now be in charge..? You mean independent clause can't be a subject or linked with other clause?

Comment: @dbwlsld *Managers formerly supervised* is not a subject *phrase*. You can't say, for instance, **[managers formerly supervised]** *employees ate bananas*. On the other hand, **[managers]** (***who*** formerly supervised employees) *ate bananas* is fine,